# UI freezes for 2-3 seconds when loading a carouselview

Tags: xamarin, async-await, xamarin.forms.carouselview

I have a carouselview binded to a viewmodel, on the previous page (call it first page) user can select 2 arguments and with the help of those, the next view (call it second page) is generated accordingly. However, I can't wrap my head around why my view won't load asynchronously.

So my problem: When I click the button on the first page the UI would freeze for like a solid 2-3 seconds, and then start load (asynchronously?) and once it's done it's all good.

Also I couldn't really figure out a better way to inherit values from first page to second so if someone has an idea please let me know.

Any help on how can I fix this I would really appreciate.

**The viewmodel for second page**

```
public class DataSelectionViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
   public ObservableCollection<Items> FilteredData { get; set; }

   public UserSelectionViewModel()
   {
            _dataStore = DependencyService.Get<IDataStore>();

            LoadData= new AsyncAwaitBestPractices.MVVM.AsyncCommand(FilterData);

            FilteredData = new ObservableRangeCollection<Items>();
   }
   public async Task FilterData()
   {
            FilteredData.Clear();
            var filtereddata = await _dataStore.SearchData(Hard, Subject).ConfigureAwait(false);
            foreach (var data in filtereddata)
            { 
                FilteredData.Add(data);
            }
   }  
}
```

**The carouselview in second page**

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <db:DataSelectionViewModel/>  
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
...
<!-- DataTemplate for carouselview has radiobuttons, label and button all in a grid -->
<CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredData}">
```

**Second Page c#**

```
public partial class SecondPage : ContentPage
{

     public Coll(bool hard, string subject)
     {
            InitializeComponent();
            var vm = (BaseViewModel)BindingContext;

            vm.Hard = hard;
            vm.Subject = subject;
            /* had to set "hard" and "subject" here again, otherwise data won't load */
     }

     protected override async void OnAppearing()
     {
         var vm = (DataSelectionViewModel)BindingContext;
         base.OnAppearing();
         await vm.LoadData.ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
     }
}
```

**The first page view containing the button**

`<Button x:Name="Start" Pressed="ButtonClick"/>`

**First page c#** --> Here I also tried doing it with a command and a pressed at the same time, because I couldn't come up with a way to save variables to second page viewmodel, that's why I use pressed here

```
private async void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var vm = (BaseViewModel)BindingContext;

   vm.Hard = HardButtonSelected == Hard;
   vm.Subject = vm.Subject.ToLower();

   await Navigation.PushAsync(new SecondPage(vm.Hard, vm.Subject));
   
}
```

I have tried not using the OnAppearing method to get my data, but then it wouldn't bind to the page and it would not show, if I were to previously fill the ObservableCollection with my data and then load the page although I would love to be able to do this because it would allow me to create a loading popup also.

Comment: does it freeze before or after the navigation?  You really need to do some digging to determine where it is freezing.  Either use the debugger to step through the code, or sprinkle some `Debug.Writeline` statements throughout the code and watch in the output window to see where the pause is.  Knowing that will help you fix the problem.  I see a number of things in the code that I would suggest changing, but nothing that is the obvious source of a multi-second delay

Comment: It freezes before the navigation, then does the navigation and page starts loading data asynchronously

Comment: ok then it is either something in the "..." or in the constructor of the 2nd page causing it

Comment: I am using CSharpMath TextView for the content of the radiobuttons, I can't think of anything else that could cause it, I updated the code in the first page c# code there is no ..., was just a mistake

Comment: Again, you need to do some digging and logging to get to the bottom of this.  Why do these two parameters `public Coll(hard, subject)` not have types?   That won't even compile.

Comment: Another mistype for me, sorry, so hypothetically you say it shouldn't freeze? What could be the culprit? I am using 2 datatemplates on the second page, they are in a grid using 6 radiobuttons and with csharpmath I use LaTeX to display the radiobutton's content

Comment: I can't actually run your code to solve this for you.  I don't see anything obvious that would cause a problem, but not every problem is obvious from just reading the code.  I've suggested several times that you need to do some logging to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: **1)** *"What could be the culprit?"* Do some tests to isolate the problem. Comment all the contents out, see if it is now fast. If it is, start adding content back, until you find what causes the freeze. **2)** *"it would not show, if I were to previously fill the ObservableCollection with my data and then load the page"* That approach should be easy to fix; consider creating a new question showing the code you tried to use. (Don't add to this question.)